# MVVM sample not working

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Following a few examples I coded my first MVVM´s demo. After binding and rendering the basic ones I am trying to bind a list of object to a listview, I´m doing something wrong but I can´t get it.

If someone could give me any clue, I´ll be grateful.

The idea is being this one:

-- VIEWMODEL --

```
    public class IntervectionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaiseOnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public IntervectionViewModel()
        {
            intervencion = new IntervectionModel();
            Intervencion1 = intervencion.Intervencion;
        }

        private List<Intervenciones> _intervencion1;
        public List<Intervenciones> Intervencion1
        {
            get { return _intervencion1; }
            set { _intervencion1 = value;  RaiseOnPropertyChange(); }
        }
   }
```

-- MODEL --

```
    public class IntervectionModel
    {
        public List<Intervenciones> Intervencion;
        public IntervectionModel()
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
//Class Intervenciones contains attribute
                Intervenciones inter = new Intervenciones(i);
                this.Intervencion.Add(inter);
            }
        }
     }

    public class Intervenciones
    {
        public string Nombre;

        public Intervenciones(int num)
        {
            this.Jefe = "JEFE" + num + " = JEFE1";
            this.Nombre = "NOMBRE" + num + " = NOMBRE1";
            this.Timer = "1:23:23";
            this.Estado = Enums.Estado.Bloqueado;
            this.Interv = new List<Tarea>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                Tarea t = new Tarea
                {
                    Titulo = this.Nombre + "%" + "TITULO = " + i,
                    Inicio = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i),
                    Duracion = i * 60,
                    Encargado = "ENCARGADO = " + i,
                    Estado = Enums.Estado.Activo,
                    Miembros = new List<string> { "Miembro" + num + " = " + i, "Miembro1" + num + " = " + i, "Miembro2" + num + " = " + i },
                    TiempoEjecucion = i + 15
                };
                Interv.Add(t);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

-- XAML.CS --

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        var p = new IntervectionViewModel();
        BindingContext = p;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

-- XAML --

```
  <ListView x:Name="sa" ItemsSource="{ Binding Intervencion1 }" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Label Text="{ Binding attribute }" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

XAML is painting 4 blue row (the list binded has 4 element), but the labels haven´t anything inside.

Thanks mates.

Comment: Is "attribute`" actually a public property of the type "Intervenciones"?

Comment: Please provide class Intervenciones.

Comment: Hi @StefanWanitzek. Yes, it is.

Comment: So you do have a public string attribute { get { return "blablabla" }}?

Comment: I don't see a property called attribute in the Intervenciones class. Please double check that! See Dominiks answer.

Comment: Hi @StefanWanitzek. Now I get it. Stupid one, sorry guys... I´m newer using MVVM...

Comment: You're welcome. MVVM is actually a pretty cool thing once you figured out how to use it.

Comment: Use Snoop to examine bindings at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class Intervenciones needs a string property "attribute" like that

```
public string attribute { get; set; }
```

**For your info:**

It has to be a property! Not a field. And actually the convention is:

```
public string Attribute { get; set; }
```

as it is a public property.

Comment: Thanks Dominik. Between Stephan and you I got the idea. I can implement a real one. Cheers Mates.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you shouldn't instantiate your ViewModel in the code behind from your View.

Try to set your ViewModel to the DataContext of the View, not the BindingContext. And it seems that you are not implementing the Property "attribute" in your Model.